# how to get overpass server to use multiple CPU / cores

Tags: overpass-api

I am running my own overpass api server version is 7.54.
I followed the instructions at https://overpass-api.de/full_installation.html
I am running on a 4 cpu machine with 8 GB of ram but the dispatcher only uses 1 cpu regardless of how much load I put on the machine and is soon overwhelmed.

How do I get overpass to use all my cpus?

Comment: Check this thread: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/344 Looks like this app is not using benefits of multi-cpu servers...

Comment: How do you define "load" and "overwhelmed"? The dispatcher does _not_ process queries, they're handled by the interpreter process. It doesn't really matter, that the dispatcher just uses 1 CPU, as CPU usage is never a bottleneck for the dispatcher. Please follow up this discussion on the Overpass Developer list.